# Help with login activity using the sharedpreference

Tags: android, eclipse, authentication, passwords, sharedpreferences

I don't know the problem of my code.

Please help.

Password.java

```
package com.android.steg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Password extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
Button submitButton;
EditText passwordEditText;
public static final String PREFS_PRIVATE = "PREFS_PRIVATE";
public static final String KEY_PRIVATE = "KEY_PRIVATE";
public static final String PREFS_READ = "PREFS_READ";
public static final String KEY_READ = "KEY_READ";
public static final String PREFS_WRITE = "PREFS_WRITE";
public static final String KEY_WRITE = "KEY_WRITE";
public static final String PREFS_READ_WRITE = "PREFS_READ_WRITE";
public static final String KEY_READ_WRITE = "KEY_READ_WRITE";



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pass);
    Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v)
{ 
    EditText passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs_file",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String password = prefs.getString("password","");
    if("".equals(password))
    {
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putString("password",passwordEditText.getText().toString());
        edit.commit();
        StartMain();
    }
    else
    {
        if(passwordEditText.getText().toString().equals(password))
        {
             StartMain();
        }
    }

}

public void StartMain()
{
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.android.steg"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:testOnly="false" android:killAfterRestore="true">
    <activity  android:name=".Password" android:label="@string/app_name" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:exported="true" android:name=".EncodeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
    <activity android:exported="true" android:name=".DecodeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="7" android:minSdkVersion="5"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA"></uses-permission>

   </manifest>
```

Pass.xml

[image]

When the Submit button is pressed it should open the MainActivity.java

My problem is every time I pressed the Submit button the application forces to close. It should switch to another activity(MainActivity).

Comment: @Cristian: what might be the problem of my code?

Comment: What is the problem?  What is happening and what is not happening?

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty: My problem is every time I pressed the Submit button the application forces to close. It should switch to another activity(MainActivity).

Comment: Can you show your stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't declared an Activity in your manifest named MainActivity.  Also, check the logcat output in the ddms tab of eclipse it will give a line number that causes the crash.

Comment: by the way can I change the password that was saved in the preferences? I mean can I change the password inside my application?

Comment: the same way you set it to begin with.  `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("password", "newpassword").commit();`